# How to modify or create a dictionary based on one dictionary querying the values of another dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dictionaries:
Dictionary A has an increasing and unique Item ID as the key and it is associated to an FID value.

Dictionary B has the FID identifiers as the keys and the values of Dict B are the associated values for each FID

```
dict_a = {11111: FID01, 22222: FID01, 33333:FID03, 44444: FID01}
dict_b = {FID01: 25, FID02: 50, FID03: 75, FID04: 90}
```

what I am hoping to do is end up with a dictionary with the Keys of Dict A corresponding directly to the correct values in Dict B

So my ideal dict C would be:

```
dict_c = {11111: 25, 22222: 25, 33333: 75, 44444: 25}
```

Not every key of dict_b will be used as a value for dict_a but every key of dict_a needs be be transferred to dict_c and corresponded to the correct value from dict_b.

I need to use Python 2.7 because this program will be used on a government computer and I can not simply download Python 3+, so any solutions built in python 2.7 would be ideal and appreciated.

I have attempted to create a list based on the dictionaries and attempting to make a new dictionary based on these lists

```
new_list = []
new_list_2 = []
for value in dict_a.values():
    if value in dict_b.keys():
        new_list.append(value)
for id in new_list():
    if item in dict_b.keys():
        new_list_2.append(dict_b.values())
```

this is returning every value for the values stored in dict_b values for each instance of a key in the new_list.  Further, if the FID number comes up more than once in Dict_a I need a new entry in the dict_c to be made.  Obviously my code above does not work and I think my logic is incorrect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
dict_a = dict({11111: "FID01", 22222: "FID01", 33333:"FID03", 44444: "FID01"} )
dict_b = dict({"FID01": 25, "FID02": 50, "FID03": 75, "FID04": 90})

dict_b_keys = dict_b.keys()

{key: dict_b[value] for (key, value) in dict_a.items() if value in dict_b_keys}
```

> {11111: 25, 22222: 25, 33333: 75, 44444: 25}

i added the "dict_b_keys" var in case you have values from dict_a which are not in dict_b keys

Answer (score 0):

This should to the trick:

```
dict_a = {11111: "FID01", 22222: "FID01", 33333: "FID03", 44444: "FID01"}
dict_b = {"FID01": 25, "FID02": 50, "FID03": 75, "FID04": 90}
dict_c = {}
for k in dict_a:
    dict_c[k] = dict_b[dict_a[k]]
print dict_c
```

Output:

```
{11111: 25, 22222: 25, 33333: 75, 44444: 25}
```

However, this is with no error-handling at all. If there is a `key` in `dict_a`, which value does not exist in `dict_b` you will get a `KeyError`